# virtualenvwrapper doesn't create /bin/ directory on mac os

Tags: python, macos, virtualenvwrapper

I installed virtualenvwrapper, ran

```
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

then ran

```
mkvirtualenv newenv
```

and got virtualenv up and running:

```
(newenv)mike:pythonbyexample mike$
```

but when I deactivated it I found nothing in my working directory, so I couldn’t activate it back again.

However the usual virtualenv command

```
virtualenv newenv2
```

worked just fine, and created a /bin/ folder with all the stuff needed

So what's wrong with the virtualenvwrapper?

My system is Mac Os, Mavericks.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

virtualenvwrapper uses the directory in `WORKON_HOME` to keep all your virtual environments. Run the following command to know where exactly they are:

```
$ echo $WORKON_HOME
```

The default `WORKON_HOME` is `$HOME/.virtualenvs`

If you want to activate `newenv` again just run:

```
$ workon newenv
```